# Counting without one-to-one correspondence?

Tags: set-theory, mathematical-philosophy, foundations, symmetry

Ash and Gross in their wonderful book [Fearless Symmetry](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/8755.html) found it worth mentioning (and thus suggesting) another way of counting for which "we do not even need to know how to count" (in the sense of being able to make one-to-one correspondences). They cite (p. 8) a young shepherd boy from Sicily in the 1950's:

> *I can't count, but even when I was a long way away, I could see if
>   one of my goats was missing. I knew every goat in my herd - it was a
>   big herd, but I could tell every one of them apart. I could tell what
>   kid belonged to what mother... The master used to count them to see if
>   they were all there, but I knew they were all there without counting
>   them.*
>  <sub>[from: [Dolci Danilo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danilo_Dolci) (1959), Report from Palermo]</sub>

I wonder if this is meant as a joke (in the sense of "the poor boy just misunderstood 'counting'. In fact he's actually counting, i.e. making unconscious mental one-to-one correspondences"), or if there is something more in it, not easy to capture in mathematical terms?

Thinking about what the shepherd boy actually does mentally (as described somehow precisely and comprehensible in his own words) lets me seem it possible that there is a essentially different way of telling whether "all goats are there: no one is missing, and no one doesn't belong to the herd (= all belong to the herd)".

Has anybody thought seriously about this? Can there be made mathematical sense out of it?

---

*[Related question: Some people are able to tell if two areas of size $n_1 \times m_1$ and $n_2 \times m_2$ are the same without being able to multiply. How do they manage?]*

Comment: Imagine the goat herd is infinite.  Then counting doesn't even tell you whether all the goats are there.  The boy just checks whether the set of goats is the same as before.

Comment: For the sake of the argument: Let's keep the herd finite.

Comment: Sure ok. So maybe the boy has amazing set-of-goats identification power that allows him to detect at a glance whether someone switched one of the goats with that of a different herd.  His silly master trusts counting and doesn’t know his set of goats as well.

Comment: If he knows all goats personally, not only the number of them,  he may mentally do many things instead of counting the *number* of goats: there are many functions of the set which allow to distinguish it from any proper subset.

Comment: This is essentially a question of psychology rather than mathematics.  If you are a parent with several children, you could probably tell if one was missing without consciously asking "Is Jack here?  Is Jill here? ...".  This shepherd is doing the same thing with goats - maybe more of them than you have children, but it's the same principle.  It's just part of the workings of the unconscious brain.

Comment: That's true: It's about counting a set of distinguishable vs. a set of indistinguishable objects. It gives the same result but works differently.

Comment: Perhaps the goats are in a certain placement, like a pigeonhole problem. If there are certain spots where the goats hang out, and one of the spots is empty, then the boy knows a goat is missing.  I might have books filling up a bookshelf, and not know how many there are on the shelf, but be able to tell if one was missing because of the space.

Comment: Or - surely there is somebody who has no idea what "one-to-one correspondence", "ten" or "five" means but can see immediately if a finger is missing on somebody's hand

Comment: May the key point is that a herd is not just a set: it has also some relations with it. So you can detect if somebody is missing if some of the relations is not verified anymore.

Comment: The shepherd boy doesn't have a different way of doing the same thing as the master -- he is doing a different thing entirely.  Let $H$ be the herd and let $P$ be the set of goats present.  The shepherd boy is determining whether $H = P$ (according to the penultimate paragraph of the question) and the master is determining whether $|H| = |P|$.  For example, if one goat from the herd is missing and is replaced by one of the neighbor's goats, the shepherd boy will detect this and the master will not.  What the shepherd boy is supposedly doing has nothing to do with one-to-one correspondences.

Comment: ... In fact, it is simpler.  In terms of the [Levy hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_hierarchy), the statements $H = P$, $H \subseteq P$, and $P \subseteq H$ can be expressed by $\Delta_0$ statements in the language of set theory, whereas the statement $|H| = |P|$ (i.e., there is a bijection between $H$ and $P$) cannot be -- it is properly $\Sigma_1$.

Comment: This doesn't add too much math content, but I haven't yet seen the term mentioned, and it seems appropriate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subitizing

Answer (score 7):

"Can there be made mathematical sense out of it?"

Perhaps as follows: given a finite set $X$ labeled with bits $y\in\{0,1\}^X$, indicating whether the corresponding element is present or missing, decide whether $\sum_{x\in X}y(x)=|X|$ or $<|X|$. This is a strictly weaker operation than counting. Certainly a counter that evaluates
$\sum_{x\in X}y(x)$
can be used to solve the decision problem, but the latter cannot be used to count (since it returns a bit rather than an integer in $[0,|X|]$).

Since the connection to psychology was mentioned in the comments, I can easily imagine a dedicated neuron for each child/goat, which is activated iff the relevant object is present. There is then a very simple schematic (and even biological) implementation of a "summation" neuron, which fires iff all of the basic inputs do. This is certainly a simpler neural circuit than a counter.

Answer (score 6):

The answer given by Robert Israel seems worth elaborating on. Knowing if everyone is present at a large family gathering is like going through the family history, or family tree: grandmother is here, her daughters A, B, and son C are here. Of course, son D isn't here, since he died in childhood. Daughter A's son E and his wife F are here with their baby son G ... et cetera. Once you know how to count, it's hard not to apply it, but it doesn't seem required if you have a form of narrative or visual memory.

Comment: Could also be a model for the "counting" abilities of animals.

Comment: As far as I know, numerical abilities in non-human animals and infants are based on numerosity-selective neurons, which are very effective for small numbers, but less accurate for larger numbers (Weber–Fechner law). It seems to me that such abilities are insufficient for accurately recognizing the size of a typical flock and don't match the specifics of the shepherd's testimony.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of rectangles, and more generally with some other shapes too, there are basically two well-known methods--cut the two given items and match the congruent pieces or complement the two items by two congruent shapes so that the two results will be congruent. These methods can be applied to simple finite arithmetics so that 1- and 2-grade children can apply them to a great advantage of the education around the world.

A general answer was already indicated in this thread. Sets may appear together with certain relations. When an element is missing then a pattern is violated. These relations/patterns don't have to be geometric or mathematical in a narrow sense, there can be--for instance--certain emotional connections, some subsets can be special (friends or enemies or a complete collection of skills (e.g. when a person is missing then the skill they possess is missing too).